# When I `ddev start` I get "Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/drud/ddev-ssh-agent/manifests/v1.6.0: unauthorized: incorrect username or password"

Tags: docker, ddev

When I `ddev start` I get "Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/drud/ddev-ssh-agent/manifests/v1.6.0: unauthorized: incorrect username or password" - How can I fix that? Why would I needto be logged into dockerhub anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for this is `docker logout`. It's unknown why this happens with docker. All of ddev's containers require no authentication at all, they're publicly available and require no authentication. But there seems to be a bug in how docker does things with authentication. Anyway, `docker logout`.