# On upgrading cypress image via DockerFile , throw an error unauthorized: incorrect username or password

Tags: docker, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline, cypress, docker-registry

Initially It was working (pulling the cypress image and container)for `FROM cypress/base:10`  . now want to upgrade cypress version to `cypress/base:16.13.0`

Below is my  **Dockerfile** :

```
# FROM cypress/base:10
FROM cypress/base:16.13.0
COPY ./cypress ./cypress
COPY ./cypress.json  ./cypress.json
COPY ./package.json ./package.json
COPY ./package-lock.json ./package-lock.json


RUN npm run cy:run
CMD ["npm", "install"]
```

As I upgraded the cypress version `cypress/base:16.13.0` it throwing an error

```
+ docker build -f Dockerfile -t testcypress .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  6.245MB

Step 1/8 : FROM cypress/base:latest
Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/cypress/base/manifests/16.13.0": unauthorized: incorrect username or password
```

**Jenkinsfile**

```
 stage('build test') {
                          steps {
                              sh ' docker build -f Dockerfile -t testcypress .'
                             }
                        }
```

- `cypress/base:16.13.0` is public image Why it is throwing error of unauthorized?
- Test is executing on jenkins server (not on my local m/c),  so can not do the docker logout , login. as suggested https://stackoverfl[ow.com/a/55049799/3302083](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55049799/3302083)
- Also tried by changing the 'docker slave Lable' from Jenkin's global configuration.

Kindly suggest how to resolved this authorization issue? Please suggest me if I need to pass dockerhub credentials  then where (jenkinfile or dockerfile )? Also suggest me syntax also ?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem, Looking for the solutions. Not sure why upgrade is not working on server where are same Dockerfile with upgraded version working very well on local machine.